Are Python class member functions argument type checked at parse time?
I'm not intending to change this in my implementation, it's to improve my understanding of porting this code:
In the extract from the track_holder.py module below, why does the TrackObject class have to be imported?
The   track   argument to  track_holder.candidate_tracks.append()   has been instantiated external to the current module, and is passed to the   .append   function without it ever being otherwise accessed  in  track_holder.py .  Surely the Python parser/interpreter does not check what type   track   is, will it pass through whatever object is passed (with potential runtime issues)?
Related - please confirm in Python that all arguments are passed by value, with no option to pass by reference.  So that local copies are made and deleted on function exit.
track_holder.py
from track_object import TrackObject

class TrackHolder:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.candidate_tracks = []

    def add_candidate_track(self, track):
        """
        track : TrackObject    Track to be added. 
"""
        self.candidate_tracks.append(track) 


Kind of related to this :
The class member function always lists 'self' as the first arg.  In some calls to the function I think I have seen something passed for this argument, in other cases not.  Is this right, you can pass in an alternative to the default class object associated with the class function call?

It doesn't have to be imported, unless you are already running some tool over your code that processes the docstring in a way that requires TrackObject to be defined.

Thank you @security-hound, I'll post questions here by default henceforth.

When Python passes an argument, it passes a pointer to this object. The pointer is passed by value (it is copied), not the argument.

Yes, Python does not care for the class of your object, either at parse time or at runtime: it gets a "Python object"  and will place that object on the list.
However, if one intends to instrument the code with optional typechecking, which happens before runtime, just as an optional step, a reference to that class, to indicate that the inner self.candidate_tracks list would contain instances of it would be needed, and you'd need the import.
For the second part of your question:

"please confirm in Python that all arguments are passed by value, with
no option to pass by reference. So that local copies are made and
deleted on function exit."

Absolutely NOT! Python passes "objects" around - that, for languages with explicit pointer semantics is the equivalent of "pass by reference" - the implication being: if any changes are made to an object inside a function, those will affect that instance, and remain "visible" outside of the function.
This is how your code could look like if you are using the optional, pre-compiling, pre-runtime, do-nothing when executing, type checking tools:
# Import required in this scenario:
from track_object import TrackObject

class TrackHolder:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.candidate_tracks: list[TrackObject] = []

    def add_candidate_track(self, track:TrackObject) -> None:
        """
        track : TrackObject    Track to be added. 
        """
        self.candidate_tracks.append(track) 


(this code if for newer Python versions  - for 3.8 or earlier, one needs to add  from typing import List and modify the variable declaration to read self.candidate_tracks: List[TrackObject] instead)

Thank you very much for your feedback.
I'm surprised that it needed until Python -V 3.9+ to allow      'tracks : list'   this is such a fundamental operation.
I'm trying to get my head around your statement that

Python passes "objects" around ... changes are made to an object inside a function, those will affect that instance

Surely you don't mean via formal argument parameters, or by declaring them 'global' inside the function?  Is "passing around" related to scope rules inside a class?

Annotations have been allowed since 3.0; Python itself doesn't do anything with them, but the typing module to start standardizing them around static type hinting appear in Python 3.5.

Thank you @chepner, that's pointed me to dig further into this.

I'm still caught up on using objects as passed-by-reference parameters, to me that is the interesting takeaway now.  I got help trying to write a simple stub that defined a basic class just to create a 1D list (a vector to me), then a function that takes this as an arg, squares it term by turn, and allows the calling segment to received the changed list object via only the "input arg list".
Below was the best suggestion, is that the simplest and best way to achieve this ?

Main program
my_list = List1D(5)  # Create a List1D object with dimension 5
my_list.square_elements()  # Square elements of my_list in-place
